# iOS 7 UIToolBar color

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uitoolbar

I have a toolBar in a tableView under iOS 7. It has this default blur and I just want to paint it black.
I am doing this:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationController.toolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationController.toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = NO;
```

With no success... The toolbar still has a "clearColor" and is still translucent.
Am I missing something?

EDIT: I am not using storyboards. The view is not loaded from Nib.
EDIT: I started a new project, and the it works. Still I have to figure out why it is not working in the first project!

Comment: have you checked that self.navigationController.toolbar is not nil?

Comment: Sure, it is showing up. Also containing all the buttons with their actions. Everything is fine, only the color is getting overwritten somewhere.

Comment: When are you calling this code?

Comment: Very good point. Got it. Was setting this in viewDidLoad instead of viewWillAppear. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

if you are using storyboards you can turn off Translucent and change the style to black in the attributes inspector tab (fourth across just before the ruler) in the utilities panel

Comment: I am not using Storyboards.

Comment: [self.navigationController.toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack]; should work then

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it on the UINavigationController. The toolbar is a property of UINavigationController, so you need to set it there. If you are not using Storyboard, you need to create a subclass.

I'm using storyboard. In Storyboard select the UINavigationController (not the embedded view!) and switch to the little shield in the right view (4th element). Then select "shows toolbar" and now you can select the toolbar and set the color.

Hope it helps!